# How to code control android studio internet is slow

Tags: android, performance, controls

While I login to android application I want to control internet speed.
If the internet is slow, how can I control it in the code?

Comment: Set connection timeout in you request.

Comment: Do you mean you want to simulate a slow connection for testing, or you want to cope with a slow connection?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using emulator for this please check the page of [Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html). There are two argument as

- netdelay `<delay>`
- netspeed `<speed>`

I think this two argument will be useful for you.